# Difference between hierarchical query and common table expression(cte)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In an interview interviewer asked what is Hierarchical Query i answered CTE 
(Common table expression ) but he said both are different
What is the different ?

Comment: Well, a CTE _can_ be recursive, but doesn't have to be. Also some databases have hierarchical datatypes such as SQL server's `hierarchyid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Magnus pointed out CTE need not be used for hierarchical queries. It can be used in any place where we need to store some data temporary upon which we want to perform some operation like applying RANK() function. As an example consider the query to find `nth` largest among a list of values. We can achieve this simply and efficiently by using CTEs.

Eg(No recursion):

```
     WITH CTE AS
        (SELECT *,
        RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Amount DESC) AS GrantRank
        FROM [Grant] )
        SELECT * FROM CTE
        WHERE GrantRank = 3
```

And of course we can use CTEs to achieve hierarchical queries using recursion.

Eg(Recursive call):

```
WITH CTE_EMPLOYEE_HEIRARCHY AS
(
    SELECT E.EmployeeID, E.ReportsTo AS Supervisor, E.FirstName, E.LastName
    FROM EMPLOYEES E WHERE E.EmployeeID = 5

    UNION ALL

    SELECT E1.EmployeeID, E1.ReportsTo AS Supervisor, E1.FirstName, E1.LastName
    FROM CTE_EMPLOYEE_HEIRARCHY 
    JOIN EMPLOYEES E1
    ON E1.ReportsTo = CTE_EMPLOYEE_HEIRARCHY.EmployeeID 

)

SELECT * FROM CTE_EMPLOYEE_HEIRARCHY
```

**References:**   1:[SQLAuthority Blog](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/07/27/sql-server-interview-questions-and-answers-guest-post-by-rick-morelan-day-27-of-31/)
             2:[Code Project Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31010/Recursion-in-SQL-using-CTE)